# Applied theme crashes on an Oreo 8.1 device

Tags: android, crash, android-theme, android-8.1-oreo

As I mess up with the crash happened in Oreo(8.1) device for an applied theme. Here is my code please check it.

```
  <activity
            android:name=".Menu_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTranslTheme" />

<style name="AppTranslTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

While I removed android:theme the app is not getting crashed. But I missed the transparency of a screen. I need that too with out crash to be happened in Oreo.Please support me to fix it.

Your answer is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: try :  <style name="AppTranslTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error log and stack trace, you will find:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
```

So the simple solution will be: remove below line from the manifest file for that activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

In android Oreo you can not change oritation for Activity just using XML if style(or parent style) has this line:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Firstly remove

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and in java file write code like this:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

May be its a bug, who knows.

If you search `Theme.Translucent` style from framework themes.xml,(press) you will find

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```